# Series expansion upto linear order

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

I want to do a series expansion of the function given below around $a=0$ and keep the terms only upto $O(a)$. The function is

$$
f(a)=\frac{a \pi^2\sin^2\theta}{a^2-\pi^2\cos^2\theta}
$$
Using $f(0)+f'(0)a$, I would get the expansion as $f(a)=-\tan^2\theta ~a$. I suspect whether this expansion would be correct near $\theta$ equal to $\pi/2$. Any help, how should I proceed in that case. Should I take $\lim~\theta\rightarrow \pi/2$ first and then do the expansion or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

There being two variables $a$ and $\theta$, you have to be careful with what $O(a)$ means, and you should probably write $f(a,\theta)$ rather than just $f(a)$.  It is true that $f(a,\theta) \sim -\frac{a}{\pi} \tan^2(\theta)$ if $\theta$ is fixed and $\cos(\theta) \ne 0$.  But if $\cos(\theta) = 0$, $f(a,\theta) = \pi/a$.  Various
other possibilities exist if $\cos(\theta) \to 0$ as $a \to 0$.  For example, if $\theta = \pi/2 + c a$ for constant $c \ne 1/\pi$,
$$ f(a,\pi/2 + c a) \sim  \frac{\pi}{1 - \pi^2 c^2} a^{-1}$$
while if $\theta = \pi/2 + a/\pi$
$$ f(a, \pi/2 + a/\pi) \sim \frac{3 \pi^3}{a^3} $$

Comment: If I say that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\pm \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a very small number so $\cos\theta$ is a small number but not exactly zero, then would $f(a)=-a~\tan^2\theta$ be true or not?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is a nonzero constant, then indeed $f(a) = -\frac{a}{\pi} \tan^2(\theta) + O(a^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that near $X=0$,

$$\frac{1}{1-X}=1+X+X^2+...$$
$$=1+O(X)$$

thus

$$f(a)=-\frac{a\pi^2\sin^2(\theta)}{\pi^2\cos^2(\theta)}\frac{1}{1-\frac{a^2}{\pi^2\cos^2(\theta)}}$$
$$=-a\tan^2(\theta)\Bigl(1+O(a^2)\Bigr)$$
$$=-a\tan^2(\theta)+O(a)$$

Comment: How are treating the denominator in $1-X$ form in this case?

Comment: @Parveen Please look again.

Comment: This doesnt address the case $\cos(\theta) \to 0$.

Comment: You got the same answer as I mentioned in my post. As $\tan^2\theta$ diverges as $\theta$ goes to $\pi/2$, I doubt whether this is correct thing to do!

Comment: If $\theta\to pi/2$ then $f(a)=\frac{\pi^2}{a}$ goes to infty when $a\to 0$.